Show that $S^2 \times S^1$ is a double cover for the connected sum $\mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP^3}$.
This question is from a publicly available practice qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. The only recommended book for this question is Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. My notation is in line with what I see commonly used in the textbooks that I study out of, but if there are requests for clarifying notation then I will happily oblige. I have seen no proof for this problem in any textbook; all work is my own, so I want to make sure my own unique solution looks good.

Question: Show that $S^2 \times S^1$ is a double cover for the connected sum $\mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP^3}$.
Answer: I go for a strategy of finding a degree 2 map everywhere. When I discuss points in the preimage, I am stating implicitly that there are disjoint neighborhoods about each point that are homeomorphic to the points in the image.
Have $X = S^2 \times S^1$. For conciseness, we'll treat $X$ as if it were a function on $S^1$: For all $x \in [0, 2 \pi)$, $X(x)$ is a copy of $S^2$.
We know from here that we can identify $\mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP}^3$ as a space $Y$ formed by taking $S^2 \times [0, \pi]$ and quotienting all antipodal points at $S^2 \times \{0\}$ and $S^2 \times \{\pi\}$. This means that at each end we have a copy of $\mathbb{RP^3}$. We'll also treat $Y$ as if it were a function on $[0, \pi]$; $Y(y)$ is a copy of $S^2$ for all $y \in (0, \pi)$, and $Y(y)$ is a copy of $\mathbb{RP^3}$ for $y = 0$ and $y = \pi$. We'll approach our proof with two cases.
Case 1:
We'll examine the case at $Y(0)$; all results will apply without loss of generality to $Y(\pi)$. We can view $Y(0)$ as being formed equivalently by taking the upper hemisphere of $S^2$ and identifying all antipodal points on the equator. It is trivial to see that all non-equatorial points of $Y(0)$ are double covered by all non-equatorial points of $X(0)$.
All antipodal points at the equator of $Y(0)$ are quotiented together. There are two corresponding disjoint antipodal points at the equator of $X(0)$ for each quotiented point in $Y(0)$. Then we can form a double cover of the equator of $Y(0)$ with the equator of $X(0)$.
Case 2:
Let's examine the case for $y \in (0, \pi)$. For each copy of $S^2$ given by $Y(y)$, we have two corresponding spheres given by $X(y)$ and $X(y + \pi)$. For example, we have a sphere $S^2$ at $Y(\pi/2)$, and two corresponding spheres at $X(\pi/2)$ and $X(3 \pi /2)$. This means that there is a double cover for every $Y(y)$, and so $X$ is a double cover of $Y$.

If there's absolutely one focus of the proof that I'm not confident on (want feedback for), it's whether my double cover on the equatorial points is sufficient for the endpoints of $Y$, since this aspect of projective space is tricky.
An optional bonus commentary on whether or not the proof itself works would be appreciated.
Even if this proof worked, I'll admit that I mainly solved this proof by visualizing each case of the problem in my head, rather than deriving things analytically. Is there a more straightforward analytic approach to the proof that makes things easier? I wasn't able to easily find a way to solve this problem using fundamental groups or homology/cohomology.

While your question is clearly a solution-verification question,  it does not meet our standards for such questions: "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

First a few comments.
Every mathematician proves things by solving it in their head, very often using visualization. The hard work is writing the proof in a rigorous manner, understanding what details need to be justified using analytic methods.
Also, this problem has nothing to do with homology/cohomology, and not too much with fundamental groups although you can do a reality check to verify for yourself that the fundamental group of $S^2 \times S^1$ is indeed isomorphic to an index $2$ subgroup of the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP}^3$ as would be true if the the desired double covering map exists.
As for the proof, your statement of the strategy is appropriate: your goal is to produce a particular function $f : S^2 \times S^1 \to \mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP}^3$ and to prove that this function is a degree 2 covering map. However, I don't actually see anywhere where you have described this function. Instead, you seem to be talking about various pieces of the function without ever addressing the function as a whole, like the parable of the blind men and the elephant.
One thing impeding you in that regard is your reliance on your earlier solution. In that solution, your main goal is again to produce a function, namely a particular homeomorphism. However, what I would suggest is that you turn your prose description of a "quotienting" operation into a rigorously described quotient map
$$g_1 : S^2 \times [0,\pi] \to \mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP}^3
$$
And then in the exact same manner you construct a quotient map $g_2 : S^2 \times [\pi,2\pi] \to \mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP}^3$.
And then you can take the union to get a quotient map $g = g_1 \cup g_2 : S^2 \times S^1 \to \mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP}^3$.
Once you have that map $g$ in your hand, your goal is to verify the requirements for a degree 2 covering map: for each point of the codomain, describe an an evenly covered open neighborhood with two homeomorphic pre-images.
As for the details of your proof, what you do say in Cases 1 and 2 is just fine, in particular you do give a convincing demonstration that the map is 2-to-1. However, what you have not done is to describe any evenly covered open neighborhoods.
